# Animate Starting of Activity Programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-transitions, activity-transition

Animate Starting of Activity Programmatically

At a high level, my project is a library that displays an activity on another activity passed-in from the integrating app.

I am trying to add a slide-up animation for the activity to be shown. Tbh, I am happy with *any* activity animations.

Since this is a library that apps will integrate, I do not want to include any animation XML files, and I do not have access to the main manifest file as well.
I need to do this programmatically.

I have tried:

```
// Activity from library
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE ); 
    requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS );

    // Create animation
    Slide slide = new Slide();
    slide.setDuration( 3000 );

    // Set enter and exit transitions
    getWindow().setEnterTransition( slide );
    getWindow().setExitTransition( slide );

    // Finally set content view
    setContentView( createContentView() );
}
```

Comment: meanwhile this is supported by the Navigation Architecture Component: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/

Answer (score 0):

So far, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this without introducing an external dependency. We're now distributing the library as an AAR, and with it comes various animation XML files which resolves the original question.